# how to separate taxonomy hierarchy in pathauto with slashes

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, routes, path-aliases

[Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) seems to have a different way of aliasing taxonomy hierarchy.

From [Taxonomy Menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu):

1. Classifieds > Cars > Aston Martin > DB9 Coupe
2. Classifieds > Jobs > Accounting

What I want is something like this for the url:

- classifieds/jobs/accounting (not accounting-jobs-classifieds)

(Note that Pathautho generates this with dashes in reverse order as well.)

In Pathauto, I'm using this pattern: `Default path pattern` (applies to all vocabularies with blank patterns below)

`[term:parents-all]`

Confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module enabled, you can set a pattern like this:

```
[term:vocabulary]/[term:parent:parent:name]/[term:parent:name]/[term:name]
```

Make this pattern as long as you want. Your paths will then become:

```
vocabulary
vocabulary/category1
vocabulary/category1/subcategory1
vocabulary/category1/subcategory2
vocabulary/category1/subcategory2/subsubcategory1
```

and so on...

Comment: Many Thanks to you! So if i have a taxonomy hierarchy 5 levels deep (including vocab) that would be [term:vocabulary]/[term:parent:parent:parent:name]/[term:parent:parent:name]/... etc.., right? I wish tokens module can be configured in such a way you don't need to define parent-child repeatedly in this manner. What if unexpectedly your tree becomes 6 levels then you would have to delete and update your paths to include another and then becomes 7 levels deep and so on.. i mean, if one user added terms one level down, he cannot see his contents unless a admin updates pathauto!

Comment: Even though this is the accepted answer, please review @NenadP's answer for a scalable solution.

Answer (score 16):

There is a clever way to do this by using **join:/**

In my case, I used:

`[node:field-taxonomy-skolski:parents:join:/]`

where `field-taxonomy-skolski` is the field for choosing the term from the taxonomy tree.
Forward slashes will be stripped, though there is a setting under

**Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » URL aliases » URL aliases** - settings

at the bottom of the page for **PUNCTUATION drop-down**. Set to slash (/) "no action" instead of "remove".

Comment: Bingo! I myself offered the above non-scalable solution (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27141/how-can-i-use-pathauto-to-generate-urls-for-deeply-nested-vocabularies/27142#27142) and of course I like this one much better. I'd swear that token option hasn't been there when I was struggling to get that pattern working. Thanks!

Comment: [...:join:/] did not work for me but [...:join-path] did. Remark: with join-path you can not choose the separator. It just uses / as separator.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, you probably need to install and enable the "entity" module.

Comment: Pattern for Drupal 8 is a little different, e.g.: 
`[term:vocabulary]/[term:parents:join:/]/[term:name]`

Answer (score 6):

This one works for me on Drupal 7.15 with Token 7.x-1.3 and Pathauto 7.x-1.2:

> [term:parents:join:/]/[term:name]

As brunops stated in the second answer, join:%separator% does the magic. It replaces the default dash with %separator%.

A big thanks to brunops!

Comment: This have to be right answer! It doesn't matter at all how many levels you have, this will work.

Answer (score 3):

The keys to getting this to work is:

- install and enable the Entity API, Entity Tokens, Path Auto and
  Taxonomy modules.
- create a field on your content type and set Field Type to Term
  Reference and name it something like 'field-content-category'
  (machine name)
- Set the Number of Values, aka, 'Maximum number of values users can
  enter for this field' to 1 (very important if you want to use the
  joined-path tokens which automatically adds a / between the path elements).
- set the URL patterns (admin/config/search/path/patterns) to something
  like
  '[node:field-content-category:parents:join-path]/[node:field_content_category]/[node:title]'

Answer (score 0):

Well I would recommend using something smart like:

[term:parent:terms:reversed:join:?]

But I cant for the life of me get it working neither. So instead I recommend the following but you can only go as deep as the hierarchy allows (can be seen in replacement patterns). If you add terms deeper in the hierarchy you will have to update the pattern also.

[term:parents-all:3]/[term:parents-all:2]/[term:parents-all:1]