# How can I use pathauto to generate URLs for deeply nested vocabularies?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I am generating breadcrumbs from URL arguments as described [here](http://drupal.org/node/698666).

I have a vocabulary that looks like this:

Arts-> Performing-> Dancing-> Ballet

I want my url to look like this:
arts/performing/dancing/ballet

Using the pathauto module, I can do this for taxonomy terms:

```
[term:parent]/[term:name]
```

Which, on the Ballet page, gives me the following; not what I want:

```
dancing/ballet
```

If I use parents instead of parent, 
(`[term:parents]/[term:name]`); this is close but not quite:

```
arts-performing-dancing/ballet
```

How can I get from `arts-performing-dancing` to `arts/performing/dancing`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a better way that scales

```
[node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:title]
```

Answer (score 9):

Try something like this as your vocabulary pattern:

```
[term:parent:parent:parent:name]/[term:parent:parent:name]/[term:parent:name]/[term:name]
```

And your last question should go away.

Just be sure to repeat the `parent:` part at least as many times as max term depth expected in your vocabulary. Pathauto will smartly skip overhead items.

I know it's not super-scalable, but it works for me.

Comment: That did it!  If performance becomes an issue I'll look for a better way, but this is definitely good enough for now.

Answer (score 4):

All these answer are right but you can also use the [Taxonomy entity index](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_entity_index)  module which provides taxonomy tokens. Problems begin when your term contains slashes.

> The taxonomy entity index module maintains a normalized index of all terms associated with a specific entity and revision. The core {taxonomy_index} table only maintains its data for published nodes. This module maintains its data for all entity types (regardless of published or not) and also indexed by revision.

Answer (score 2):

If you find pattern for Drupal 8, use `[term:parents:join:/]/[term:name]`

Example result: `arts/performing/dancing`

Because our delimiter is slash, don't forget to disable removing the slashes in **Administration > Configuration > Search and metadata > URL aliases > Settings**, go to /admin/config/search/path/settings, **Punctuation** section, find **Slash (/)** and choose "No action (do not remove)" in dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following pattern for the path alias: `[term:i18n-vocabulary]/[term:parents:join-path]/[term:i18n-name]`.