# How to Display Hierarchical Vocabulary Terms in URL Pattern Separated with Slashes

Tags: tokens, path-aliases, entities

I'm not sure if this is the appropriate place for this question (I'm a self-proclaimed newbie)...I have a vocabulary with the following scheme:

```
category1
    subcategory1a
    subcategory1b
```

I'm trying to create a URL pattern for the content path so it has the following URL pattern: category1/subcategory1a/[node:title].  I have Drupal 7.22, Entity API 7.x-1.0-rc3, Token 7.x-1.1, and Pathauto 7.x-1.1 and have been trying different token patterns in the URL aliases
section.  If I set the pattern to be [node:field-VOCABULARYNAME]/[node:title], then the URL alias generated is: `category1-subcategory1a/[node:title].`
Is there a way to have a "/" appear between the parent term and subterm instead of a dash?

Or is there a way to create the pattern: `[node:field-VOCABULARYNAME:0]/[node:field-VOCABULARYNAME:1]/[node:title]?`

The tokens related to individual content items ("nodes") listed are:

```
[node:field-VOCABULARYNAME]
    [node:field-VOCABULARYNAME:1]
    [node:field-VOCABULARYNAME:2]
    [node:field-VOCABULARYNAME:3]
```

If I set the pattern to `[node:field-VOCABULARYNAME]/[node:field-VOCABULARYNAME:1]/[node:title]`, then the URL alias generated is: `category1-subcategory1a/subcategory1a/[node:title]`.

In my content type, I have the field that's tied to the vocabulary is set up as a Hierarchical Select widget with Term reference as the field type.

I found these [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311545/drupal-7-pathauto-hierarchical-taxonomy-terms-pattern) and [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20311/how-to-separate-taxonomy-hierarchy-in-pathauto-with-slashes) posts and it seemed most relevant to me, but I do not have the taxonomy term tokens listed.

Thank you for your guidance

Comment: Dear Nikhil M, thank you for the link!  I hadn't seen that one yet and it provided me with the answer.  I needed to download the Taxonomy Entity Index module and then I could enter [node:terms:join:/]/[node:title] as the pattern.

Comment: in case it may be of help to others, the link that Nikhil M provided was http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27141/how-can-i-use-pathauto-to-generate-urls-for-deeply-nested-vocabularies