# Pathauto url of term for node?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

With Pathauto, is it possible to use the url of a node's term as a token?

In case it makes a difference im using the Taxonomy Menu module aswell. Thanks

UPDATE - The taxonomy is hierarchical. So if I have:

Food/Pizza/Margareta

Then if a node is tagged with 'Margareta' I need the path to be:

Food/Pizza/Margareta/node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taxonomy terms are attached to nodes using term reference fields in Drupal 7. As such, you have access to the term reference field just like any other in the list of replacement tokens.

Look for fields related to the node with a description of "Term reference field", e.g.

[image]

EDIT:

To address your edit, I know it looks ridiculous but something like this will probably work (using `field_school` as an example):

```
[node:field-school:vocabulary]/[node:field-school:parent:parent:name]/[node:field-school:parent:name]/[node:field-school:name]
```

Here's another screenshot showing the extra data available for term reference fields in pathauto:

[image]

Comment: Ive updated my question. Your solution only adds the last term to the url and I have a hierarchical taxonomy structure. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you've got the Token module installed and have a look at [this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20311/how-to-separate-taxonomy-hierarchy-in-pathauto-with-slashes), it's got the answer you're looking for :)

Comment: Ive used that answer to get the urls working properly for the terms, however I cant get them working for the nodes. Thanks

Comment: @jdln I've updated the answer, hope it helps

Comment: [node:field_tax] returns the node's term, but none of the terms parents.

Comment: All of the following return an error: [node:field_tax:name]
[node:field_tax:parent]
[node:field_tax:parent:name]

Comment: The error is: The Pattern for all product-display-my paths is using the following invalid tokens: [node:field_tax:name].

Comment: @jdln I've added another screenshot showing how you should be able to drill down into your term reference fields to actually choose the token you're after. I've been using this method for a long time, and it's [standard practice](http://drupal.org/node/1044980) by all accounts. Hope that helps

Comment: Working! I needed to go to my content type and set the maximum number of terms that a node can be tagged with to 1. Annoying limitation as my nodes will need multiple tags, but ive read something about using multiple fields to get round this.