# Where are the term tokens gone?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, tokens, path-aliases, uri

I have a hard time setting up URL alias patterns when it comes to taxonomy terms. Especially, I'm stunned that in the Replacement under Content Paths, a term reference field shows just one flat item [node:field_term_name], rather than an expandable set of taxonomy-related tokens. This is the way it used to be (as in the screenshot here: [Pathauto url of term for node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28154/pathauto-url-of-term-for-node))
Have things changed or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the Entity_Token sub module does help with this issue, however, you need to add a "Term Reference" type field to any of your content types in order to see your taxonomy vocabulary be listed as one of the replacement tokens.
In my case, I had enabled the entity_tokens module but I was still not able to see my vocabulary as one of the replacement tokens.  Then I added a new field to my "basic page" content type.  The field type I added was "term reference" and I selected my custom vocabulary as its default vocabulary.  This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I found out what was wrong. The key was to enable Entity Token (a submodule of the Entity API package). Following that all the taxonomy reference field's tokens expanded into a subtree and my Pathauto i18n patterns started to work as desired.