# Page Categorisation and Multi-level Paths

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases, uri

I want to categorise my pages and see the category names in path.

For example: instead of http://localhost/a-funny-story, http://localhost/stories/funny/a-funny-story.

What is the best practice? I tried to do it with Pathauto module. I created a content type with a term reference of a category taxonomy.

I use this pattern `[node:field_my_page_category]/[node:title]` in "CONTENT PATHS". But this doesn't work for multi-level categories. I tried to use "join" `[node:field_my_page_categories:parents:join:/]/[node:title]`  as mentioned [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/29056/46525).

But I get this error: `The Pattern for all Sayfa paths is using the following invalid tokens: [node:field_my_page_category:parents:join:/]`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a node, you need to use Pathauto and also `Replacement Patterns`, in the `Replacement Patterns` select the taxonomy term and put it in the url.

[image]

But if you need to list set of contents based on the url you need to use Views and add the terms as contextual filters.

Comment: I edited my post about details you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling **Entity Tokens** module and changing the pattern to `[node:field_my_page_categories:parents:join:/]/[node:field_my_page_categories:name]/[node:title]` solved my problem.